# Creating Java Compiler that displays errors and output

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I'm trying to create a program that compiles Java code put into a text area code and then runs it. I'm stuck on outputting error messages and results of running the created file to a JTextArea called 'Output'. I want it to be like eclipse or JCreator where compiler or runtime errors are displayed in the 'output' area and System.out.println displays the Strings in the 'output' area too. Right now when I output the results of running the file I get a message in the 'output' text area such as java.io.FileInputStream@96e380c

Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code just for the 'Run' button

```
btnRun.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // write non-lambda file
    try {
        nonLambda = new File("nonLambda.java");
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(nonLambda));
        writer.write(nLambdaTA.getText());
        writer.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    // compile non-lambda file
    try {
        Process compile = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac nonLambda.java");
        output.setText(compile.getErrorStream().toString());
    } catch(Exception e3) {
        output.setText(e3.toString());
    }
    // run non-lambda file
    try {
        Process run = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -cp " +
                nonLambda.getParent()+nonLambda.getName());
        output.setText(run.getErrorStream().toString());
        //output.append("\n"+run.getOutputStream().toString());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(run.getInputStream()));
        String ch = new String();
        while((ch=br.readLine())!=null)
            output.append(ch+"\n");
    } catch (Exception e4) {
        output.append("\n" + e4.toString());
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Processes run concurrently, so you won't necessarily have any output unless you `waitFor()` them to complete, otherwise you'll have incomplete output. That, and this doesn't do what you think it does:

`output.setText(compile.getErrorStream().toString());`

`toString()` on an `InputStream` does *not* drain the stream to produce a string of chars; it's probably just `Object.toString()`.

Comment: Your ```Process``` object. The general idea is to have two other threads copying the InputStreams over to buffers in memory (possibly even updating the UI in real time) as the main thread waits for the process to complete.

Comment: could you give me some sample code?? Never used processes before, and only had 1 assignment this year (1st year Uni) on inputStreams. Just playing around with this as a summer project